# apache RewriteCond doesn't match empty http_referer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to realize something like this:

When someone opens a browser and access http://www.example/controller.php directly, then the request will be redirected to the error page. However, if a user clicks a link with http://www.example/controller.php on my website, the request will be redirected to http://www.example/controller

To do so, I write the following rewriterule in .htaccess file:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/controller\.php
   RewriteCond %[HTTP_REFERER] ^$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/controller/error [R,L]
```

But unfortunately `RewriteCond %[HTTP_REFERER] ^$` is not matched. My all other rewriterules are working fine. To discard the side effect of other rewriterules, I delete all the other rules but it still doesn't work. 
So I guess maybe %[HTTP_REFERER] is not empty when a url is directly accessed from the browser. Then I write the following rule right before the rewriterule above:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.google.com/?referer=%{HTTP_REFERER} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

And this redirects to https://www.google.com/?referer=

So %[HTTP_REFERER] is well and truly empty.

I completely have no idea now, and any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no `%[HTTP_REFERER]`.  Did you mean `%{HTTP_REFERER}`?

Comment: MY GOD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot. I'm really really stupid.........

Comment: Keep in mind that the HTTP referer header is an optional header that may be omitted, mangled or spoofed, and you can't guarantee its presence or validity.